# Native class construction in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am defining a class in native and constructing that native class object from JS and I am trying to call native class api's using object of that class which i have created in js file. As you can see in the below code.
**i am using v8 for parsing.**
    var p = new myclass();
        p.myfunc();
**this myfunc() is native api, which i am trying to call from js using class object.**
I'm getting the following message:

> TypeError: Illegal constructor

Comment: And what does the `myclass` function look like ?

Comment: What do you mean by creating one class *in native*? Where is the definition of `myclass`? Also, JavaScript does not have classes. It has prototype-based object orientation.

Comment: yes i am defining a class in native, and need to expose class from the v8 javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example:

Declare your class as following

```
function MyClass(){
   //declare any instance variable
   this.Name = 'myClass';

   //declare any instance method
   this.ChangeName = function (newName)
   {
      this.Name = newName;
   }
}
```

Instance it:

```
var instance = new MyClass();
```

Use it:

```
Console.log(instance.Name); // logs "myClass"
instance.ChangeName('foo');
Console.log(instance.Name); // logs "foo"
```

Comment: Here is the proper way of defining a method : `Class.prototype.method = function(){};`.

Comment: That's just a matter of syntax: I'm used to my syntax as IMHO it's more readable

Comment: @wared why is that the proper way? It's a *different* way, and doesn't do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas actually it's not only matter of syntax. If you declare your method inside the constructor without using `prototype`, each instance of `MyClass` will have a unique `ChangeName` method. If you declare it the way `wared` suggested, the method will be available in `MyClass` instances, but will belong to your function prototype, not to each object. In general, I think it's better to follow his approach. That's how native JavaScript objects (`String`, `Number`, `Boolean`) work.

Comment: @brbcoding Well, this is not THE proper way. I was googling here and there to find any reason for that and, indeed, it seems that I failed ^^' Shame on me... That said, these two methods do not do the same thing since prototype methods are shared across all instances unlike instance methods. Check this stuff : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/D3nra/.

Comment: Nice to know... a question: prototype method have access to instance variables as well? (this.Name in my example)

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas `foo.speak('Yes it does.')` gives `"Foo : Yes it does."`.